# Calling delegate from (get, set )Properties c#

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates

I need help to use the below piece of code to call `Method1`. There are no compilation issues but while running the code `Method1` is not invoked. I searched the net a lot but didn't find a solution.

```
public static class Test12

{

public static Test12.ByteDelegate PropertyValue { get; set; }

public delegate byte[] ByteDelegate(byte p1, byte[] p2);        

}
```

The above class has to be used like this:

```
class Abc

{

internal void Stat()        
{              
    Test12.Propertyvalue = Method1;                       
}
private byte[] Method1(byte p1, byte[] p2)
{
    byte[] abc = ...;
    return abc;
}
}
```

If I am creating an instance of the delegate in stat method and using it like:

```
Method1(param1,param2);
```

Then the `Method1` in invoked, but if I use it like this:

```
Test12.PropertyValue = Method1(param1,param2);
```

compiler is throwing an error saying missing typecast. Can anybody please tell me how to invoke `Method1` using `Test12.PropertyValue = Method1;`?

Comment: It would really help if you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions, format your code more readably, and provide a [mcve] rather than bits and pieces.

Comment: But fundamentally, if you *call* the method, that will return a `byte[]`... and your property isn't of type `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You receive an error message because when you try to assign the method to the delegate you are using the following line of code:

```
 test12.propertyvalue = method1(param1, param2);
```

Which firstly calls the `method1` and then what it returns it's trying to assign to the delegate, and the error message occurs saying that you can't assign a byte array to a delegate, as @Jon said in the comment. They are different types so you can't assign one to another, at least not without a cast or a conversion method.

In order to invoke the `method1` from the delegate, after you do the assignation like this:

```
 test12.propertyvalue = method1;
```

you can simply call the delegate, as it would be your method:

```
 test12.propertyvalue(param1 , param2);
```